# Android debug cannot see files using USB Type C converter

Tags: android, usb

Took me a while to fix this problem so thought this may help with Q&A.
Trying to debug Android app on my new Nexus 5. Able to enable developer mode in normal manner but not visible in Chrome when connected by USB using a USB cable that had a Micro USB to Type C converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB Type C converter seemed to only support charging. I bought a USB cable with Type C end point and this solved the problem. Phone was now visible in Chrome.

Comment: But isn't it discharging your phone?

Comment: Maybe I could have been clearer. I was initially using a Type C Converter attached to a Micro USB connection to fit my Google Nexus 5 (which has a Type C female). It charged ok but would not debug. A new USB Type C cable (ie without the Converter) charged and also allowed depugging.